# Scrapy: extracting data

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that gets links to profiles. But information is not collected on the profiles page. What is the problem?

```
custom_settings = {
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36 OPR/60.0.3255.50747 OPRGX/60.0.3255.50747',
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 2.5,
    }

    def start_requests(self): 
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.ratemds.com/best-doctors/?specialty=acupuncturist', callback=self.profile_link)
    
    def profile_link(self, response):
        for a in response.css('.search-item-doctor-link'):
            yield response.follow(a, callback=self.profile)
            
        next_page = response.css('.pagination-sm a::attr(href)')[-1].get()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.profile_link)

    def profile(self, response):
 
        item =  {
                'url': response.request.url,
                'Image': response.css('.doctor-profile-image::attr(src)').get(),
                'First_and_Last_Name': response.css('h1::text').get(),
                'Position': response.css('.col-sm-6 .search-item-info~ .search-item-info+ .search-item-info span::text').getall(),
                'Reviews': response.css('.star-rating-count span span::text').get(),
                'Gender': response.css('.fa-male+ a::text').get(),
                'Facilities': response.css('.search-item-extra a span::text').getall(),
            }

        yield item
```

output:

```
{'url': 'https://www.ratemds.com/doctor-ratings/dr-zach-olesinski-toronto-on-ca', 'Image': None, 'First_and_Last_Name': None, 'Position': [], 'Reviews': None, 'Gender': None, 'Facilities': [], 'Social_Media_link': None, 'Staff': 0, 'Punctuality': 0, 'Helpfulness': 0, 'Knowledge': 0, 'Comments': [], 'Facility_Affiliations': [], 'Accepting_New_Patients': None, 'Languages': [], 'Education': [], 'Other_Specialties': [], 'Areas_of_Expertise': [], 'Awards_Recognitions': [], 'Publications_Research': [], 'Insurance_accepted_by_this_Doctor': []}
```

Comment: that website has captcha protection, so please check your response from website, (response.body)

Comment: @Roman What do you have in mind? Please tell more.

Comment: log response.body inside you  `profile_link` method, to see the response which you receive from the server. Looks like you redirected to page with captcha or you receive a response that doesn't contain the required information.